# How do you reset the Zoom in Visual Studio 2010 and above

Tags: visual-studio, ide

How do you reset the "Zoom" in VS 2010 and above back to normal?

`CTRL+SCROLL WHEEL` lets you zoom in/out with Visual Studio 2010/2012/2013/2015/2017, but I'd like to get back to the initial 100%.

Comment: It's Ctrl+0 in most browsers... worth a shot

Comment: I tried the same Ctrl+0 approach the first time this happened to me. Since that doesn't work here and interacting with that zoom section is horribly slow, on machines where I don't ever need to present to a room full of people (read: all of them), I installed the ["Disable Mouse Wheel Zoom"](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d088791c-150a-4834-8f28-462696a82bb8) extension from Noah Richards. It leaves the zooming keyboard shortcuts available (Ctrl+Shift+Comma and Ctrl+Shift+Period).

Comment: Good extension. Found it answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2861655/how-do-i-disable-zoom-on-control-scroll-in-visual-studio-2010

Comment: Thanks @patridge for answering the corollary:  at last I know what I've been fumble-fingering to inadvertently zoom in and out, Ctrl+Shift+Period and Ctrl+Shift+Comma.

Answer (score 524, accepted):

There is a select box for this at the bottom left of the editor window - choose 100% ;)

[image: zoom control]

I was unable to find a keyboard shortcut for it, though zooming in and out can be done using <kbd>Ctrl + ></kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + <</kbd>.

Please note the horizontal scroll bar must be turned on to see the zoom level.

Tools / Options / Text Editor / All Languages / Scroll Bars

---

Another option (Visual Studio 2013/2015) is to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with the mouse wheel (up to zoom in, down to zoom out).

Comment: @jocull, because it's tucked away in a horrible location in a cluttered UI. The worst part is that there isn't even a zoom option/submenu in the "view" menu, where it belongs.

Comment: @zzzzBov Well the VS 2010 UI isn't actually very cluttered.  It's actually quite clever, but I think because your code is symbols and numbers and %, this box is easy to miss.

Comment: @bobobobo, Everywhere you look in visual studios there is another button, menu, action, feature, or text. There isn't a significant amount of whitespace for anything by default. Those are the indicators used to determine that a layout is cluttered. Being clever doesn't make it *not* cluttered.

Comment: @zzzzBov That's just Microsoft exposing the software's features to you. The development window is actually huge, toolbars can be customized or removed, and every side menu can be ripped off or put away. More, it has a fullscreen mode. It's a well designed application, and it isn't cluttered unless _you_ set it up wrong.

Comment: @bobobobo, a program's layout is judged by its defaults. And even with massive amounts of customization (which I assure you I take full advantage of), the layout maximizes its usage of space. That's basically the definition of a cluttered layout. I'm not saying that it's bad, I'm saying that it's got a high ratio of content to screen real-estate. The major issue with cluttered spaces is that it's really easy to miss small things. If you've got an empty room and your keys are in the middle of it, you can spot them easily. No one has an empty room, because it's not functional. VS is functional.

Comment: I've always known this box is there, but I would always inadvertently trigger zooming in and out with Magic Trackpad/Parallels combo. @patridge's suggestion to use https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d088791c-150a-4834-8f28-462696a82bb8 is golden!

Comment: At least in my case, you can only see it if you have the Package Manager Console tab selected

Comment: To those not seeing the zoom box, it needs the horizontal scrollbar visible. [Here’s the setting for that](https://i.imgur.com/fPBUlV1.png)

Comment: even worse, when you start typing in the search-box (quick-launch) for "zoom", it doesn't show anything useful.

Comment: WHY do I need the horizontal scroll bar to see the zoom level?!

Comment: Even though I know that control is there, I always have trouble finding it. I expect it to be located where other products (eg word excel) put it.

Comment: It must be the 10th time I'm here.

Comment: Unfortunately, in VS2019, there is no zoom control as you show on the horizontal bar!  Is there an extension for this?   -- EDIT:  There's only a zoom in the code view. Bummer (have to use the menus in form view)

Comment: LOL, it's 2024, using VS since 90s, never seen this feature in my whole life. ROFLMAO

Answer (score 23):

There's a zoom control in the bottom-left of the code editor.  You can pick 100% from there, or type it by hand.

Comment: To those not seeing the zoom box, it needs the horizontal scrollbar visible. [Here’s the setting for that](https://i.imgur.com/fPBUlV1.png)

Comment: @Timwi Question not asked, but answer sought.

Comment: Unfortunately, in VS2019, there is no zoom control as you show on the horizontal bar!  Is there an extension for this?

Answer (score 22):

In **Visual Studio 2022** (easy to miss if using a dark theme):

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, in VS2019, there is no zoom control as you show on the horizontal bar!  Is there an extension for this?

Answer (score 9):

You can try [VSCommands extension from Visual Studio Gallery](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/d491911d-97f3-4cf6-87b0-6a2882120acf), it adds several new features around zooming in VS2010

[image]

Comment: I wish they also had tools to disable all these evil popup hinting balloons in text editor screen which block the view of the code I need to see.

Answer (score 9):

Visual Studio 2017 has an extension "Reset Zoom" by Mads Kristensen and it adds a keyboard shortcut (Ctrl+0, Ctrl+0).
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ResetZoom

By default, the keyboard shortcut is Ctrl+0,Ctrl+0 but can be changed to be whatever you like.

I also have R# and the default shortcut did not show up for me but manually applying it worked.

Go to Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard and look for the command View.ZoomReset to change the keyboard shortcut.

Answer (score 2):

In **Visual Studio Ultimate 2013**, at bottom-left from screen:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using latest version you can also resize the content in visual studio by selecting

> ctrl+  will zoom in and ctrl- will zoom out.

to do manually goto

> preference->settings

and  ***UserSetting*** file will be opened in the editor change.For default zoom

> window.zoomlevel:0

and to zoom in

> window.zoomlevel:1,2,3......

Comment: You may be thinking of Visual Studio Code.