# How do I fix Visual Studio 2010 zooming on scroll even after I release the control key?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

My Visual Studio 2010 has gotten into a state where ordinary use of the mouse wheel (ie without the control key pressed) results in text increasing or decreasing in size.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 7):

Press the control key again and scroll on the page to recover from this state.

(This answer extracted from [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010408/1512) because people seemed to be finding the answer useful there even though it's not relevant to the question being asked there.)

Comment: For me this only worked with right control button.  Left control didn't reset the behavior.