# vs.net mouse scroll keeps resizing my text, how to get out of this mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Once in a while I do something, and whenever I use my mouse to scroll my code the text gets larger/smaller.

I hit escape etc., but I can't get out of this mode w/o having to restart vs.net.

What is the secret?

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about?

Comment: maybe your ctrl button got stuck ?

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>CTRL + scrollwheel</kbd> zooms the IDE. Hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key a few times or blur the window (i.e. take focus away from it, sometimes VS gets confused).

- [More about zooming/zoom configuration](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2010/04/15/visual-studio-2010-zooming-keyboard-commands-global-zoom.aspx) in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

**In short:** this happens because **while scrolling mouse** you may accidentally hold the `Ctrl` key on your keyboard. Once you release your **Ctrl** key this zoom IN/OUT behavior should stop.

You may effectively disable this behavior - [How do I disable zoom on control-scroll in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2861655/1437962).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ctrl + scrolldown/scrollup results in zoom out/in.You can use the dropdown containing the zoom level(in percent) at the bottom left of the screen in source window to revert it back to normal. 100% is the normal zoom percentage.